# How to solve access violation writing location error?

Tags: memory-management, access-violation

I have a simple program and I get access violation at `*(str + start)`. Why? I should be able to change it. Right?

```
void fn()
{
     char *str = "Hello wordl!";
     int end = strlen(str);
     int start = 0;
     end--;
     while(start < end)
     {
         *(str + start) = *(str + end);  <--- Access violation writing location *(str + Start).
         end--;
         start++;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 29):

`char *str = "Hello World";` is a const string, and cannot be modified.  The compiler is free to put it into a non-writable location, resulting in the crash you see.

Replacing the declaration with `char str[] = "Hello World";` should do what you want, putting the string into a modifiable array on the stack.

Comment: char str[] versus char* str results in the string being modifiable.

Comment: Here's a couple references to this:
http://www.iso-9899.info/wiki/StringsByExample

https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/cplusplus/STR30-CPP.+Do+not+attempt+to+modify+string+literals

Answer (score 4):

No, you should not. "Hello world" is a constant string literal, you need to allocate memory using [malloc()](http://man.cx/malloc) in C, or [new](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/new/operator%20new%5B%5D.html) in C++ if you want memory you are free to modify.

Answer (score 3):

As others have pointed out, literal strings may be stored in a read-only area of memory. Are you compiling with warnings turned on? You should get a warning about discarding the constness of the string literal.

What you can do instead is:

```
char *str = strdup("Hello, world!");
// Modify the string however you want
free(str);
```

Answer (score 2):

It's because you're writing to a string literal's storage, which may be in a protected area of memory.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, Hello wordl! is constant string, any attempt to modify this constant string will result in an exception.
Instead, You can do this -

```
string s = "Hello wordl!";
char* ptr = &s[0];
```

and then play around with ptr.